# What's the fastest algorithm for sorting a linked list?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, linked-list, complexity-theory

I'm curious if O(n log n) is the best a linked list can do.

Comment: Just so that you know, O(nlogn) is the bound for comparison based sorts. There are non-comparison based sorts than can give O(n) performance (e.g. counting sort), but they require additional constraints on the data.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/19738326/12597

Answer (score 111, accepted):

It is reasonable to expect that you cannot do any better than O(N log N) in *running time*.

However, the interesting part is to investigate whether you can sort it [in-place](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm), [stably](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_sort#Stability), its worst-case behavior and so on.

Simon Tatham, of Putty fame, explains how to [sort a linked list with merge sort](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/algorithms/listsort.html).  He concludes with the following comments:

> Like any self-respecting sort algorithm, this has running time O(N log N). Because this is Mergesort, the worst-case running time is still O(N log N); there are no pathological cases.
>
> Auxiliary storage requirement is small and constant (i.e. a few variables within the sorting routine). Thanks to the inherently different behaviour of linked lists from arrays, this Mergesort implementation avoids the O(N) auxiliary storage cost normally associated with the algorithm.

There is also an example implementation in C that work for both singly and doubly linked lists.

As @Jørgen Fogh mentions below, big-O notation may hide some constant factors that can cause one algorithm to perform better because of memory locality, because of a low number of items, etc.

Comment: This is not for single linked list. His C code is using *prev and *next.

Comment: @L.E. It's actually for *both*. If you see the signature for `listsort`, you'll see you can switch by using the parameter `int is_double`.

Comment: @L.E.: here's [a Python version of the `listsort` C code](https://gist.github.com/zed/5651186) that supports *only* singly-linked lists

Comment: O(kn) is theoretically linear, and can be achieved with bucket sort.  Assuming a reasonable k (number of bits /size of object you are sorting), it might be a bit faster

Answer (score 82):

Depending on a number of factors, it may actually be faster to copy the list to an array and then use a [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).

The reason this might be faster is that an array has much better
cache performance than a linked list. If the nodes in the list are dispersed in memory, you
may be generating cache misses all over the place. Then again, if the array is large you will get cache misses anyway.

Mergesort parallelises better, so it may be a better choice if that is what you want. It is also much faster if you perform it directly on the linked list.

Since both algorithms run in O(n * log n), making an informed decision would involve profiling them both on the machine you would like to run them on.

## Update

I decided to test my hypothesis and wrote a C-program which measured the time (using `clock()`) taken to sort a linked list of ints. I tried with a linked list where each node was allocated with `malloc()` and a linked list where the nodes were laid out linearly in an array, so the cache performance would be better. I compared these with the built-in qsort, which included copying everything from a fragmented list to an array and copying the result back again. Each algorithm was run on the same 10 data sets and the results were averaged.

These are the results:

| N | merge sort (fragmented) | Array w/qsort | merge sort (packed) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1,000 | <1 ms | <1 ms | <1 ms |
| 100,000 | 39 ms | 25 ms | 9 ms |
| 1,000,000 | 1,162 ms | 420 ms | 112 ms |
| 100,000,000 | 364,797 ms | 61,166 ms | 16,525 ms |

[image]

### Conclusion

At least on my machine, copying into an array is well worth it to improve the cache performance, since you rarely have a completely packed linked list in real life. It should be noted that my machine has a 2.8GHz Phenom II, but only 0.6GHz RAM, so the cache is very important.

Comment: Good comments, but you should consider the non-constant cost of copying the data from a list to an array (you'd have to traverse the list), as well as the worst case running time for quicksort.

Comment: O(n * log n) is theoretically the same as O(n * log n + n), which would be including the cost of the copy.

For any sufficiently large n, the cost of the copy really shouldn't matter; traversing a list once to the end should be n time.

Comment: @DeanJ: Theoretically, yes, but remember that the original poster is putting forth the case where micro-optimizations matter.  And in that case, the time spent turning a linked-list into an array has to be considered.  The comments are insightful, but I'm not completely convinced it would provide performance gain in reality.  It might work for a very small N, perhaps.

Comment: @csl: Actually, I'd expect the benefits of locality to kick in for large N. Assuming that cache misses are the dominant performance effect, then the copy-qsort-copy approach results in about 2*N cache misses for the copying, plus the number of misses for the qsort, which will be a small fraction of N*log(N) (since most accesses in qsort are to an element close to a recently-accessed element). The number of misses for the merge sort is a larger fraction of N*log(N), since a higher proportion of comparisons cause a cache miss. So for large N, this term dominates and slows down mergesort.

Comment: As against this, mergesort is stable and quicksort isn't. Plus you need to conditionally bail out of quicksort to avoid O(N^2) worst-case. So it may not always be a drop-in replacement, since "faster but gives a different answer" sometimes isn't acceptable. But Jørgen's results certainly show a marked benefit with a decent-sized N.

Comment: @Steve: You are right that qsort is not a drop-in replacement, but my point is not really about qsort vs. mergesort. I just didn't feel like writing another version of the mergesort when qsort was readily available. The standard library is *way* more convenient than rolling your own.

Comment: This is an exceptionally thorough answer: thanks! Question, though: how did you generate the fragmented vs. packed lists?

Comment: Each node in the fragmented list was allocated with whichever version of `malloc()` came with GLibc on Linux when I ran the test. I just allocated them inside a loop, so the memory is likely to have been less fragmented than it would have been in practice. The packed list was stored in a single contiguous piece of memory where each node originally pointed to the one immediately succeeding it. This means that the entire linked list could be traversed in its original order in a single linear scan.

Comment: The packed list with merge sort seems unusually quick, is there a chance that the packed list merge sort was operating on an already sorted list?

Comment: I am fairly confident that it was not operating on a sorted list, although it is hard to be 100% certain after so many years and without access to the source code. I would probably not even have performed this experiment today, since there could be a myriad reasons why one implementation might be faster than another, regardless of which algorithm is actually "better".

Answer (score 10):

This is a nice little paper on this topic.  His empirical conclusion is that Treesort is best, followed by Quicksort and Mergesort.  Sediment sort, bubble sort, selection sort perform very badly.

A COMPARATIVE STUDY OF LINKED LIST SORTING ALGORITHMS
by Ching-Kuang Shene

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.31.9981

Answer (score 8):

Comparison sorts (i.e. ones based on comparing elements) cannot possibly be faster than `n log n`. It doesn't matter what the underlying data structure is. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort).

Other kinds of sort that take advantage of there being lots of identical elements in the list  (such as the counting sort), or some expected distribution of elements in the list, are faster, though I can't think of any that work particularly well on a linked list.

Answer (score 5):

As stated many times, the lower bound on comparison based sorting for general data is going to be O(n log n).  To briefly resummarize these arguments, there are n! different ways a list can be sorted.  Any sort of comparison tree that has n! (which is in O(n^n)) possible final sorts is going to need at least log(n!) as its height: this gives you a O(log(n^n)) lower bound, which is O(n log n).

So, for general data on a linked list, the best possible sort that will work on any data that can compare two objects is going to be O(n log n).  However, if you have a more limited domain of things to work in, you can improve the time it takes (at least proportional to n).  For instance, if you are working with integers no larger than some value, you could use [Counting Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) or [Radix Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort), as these use the specific objects you're sorting to reduce the complexity with proportion to n.  Be careful, though, these add some other things to the complexity that you may not consider (for instance, Counting Sort and Radix sort both add in factors that are based on the size of the numbers you're sorting, O(n+k) where k is the size of largest number for Counting Sort, for instance).

Also, if you happen to have objects that have a perfect hash (or at least a hash that maps all values differently), you could try using a counting or radix sort on their hash functions.

Answer (score 3):

Not a direct answer to your question, but if you use a [Skip List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list), it is already sorted and has O(log N) search time.

Comment: _expected_ `O(lg N)` search time - but not guaranteed, as skip lists rely on randomness. If you are receiving untrusted input, be sure the supplier of the input cannot predict your RNG, or they could send you data that triggers its worst case performance

Answer (score 3):

A [Radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) is particularly suited to a linked list, since it's easy to make a table of head pointers corresponding to each possible value of a digit.

Comment: Can you please explain more on this topic or give any resource link for radix sort in linked list.

Answer (score 2):

Merge sort doesn't require O(1) access and is O ( n ln n ). No known algorithms for sorting  general data are better than O ( n ln n ).

The special data algorithms such as radix sort ( limits size of data ) or histogram sort ( counts discrete data ) could sort a linked list with a lower growth function, as long as you use a different structure with O(1) access as temporary storage.

Another class of special data is a comparison sort of an almost sorted list with k elements out of order. This can be sorted in O ( kn ) operations.

Copying the list to an array and back would be O(N), so any sorting algorithm can be used if space is not an issue.

For example, given a linked list containing `uint_8`, this code will sort it in O(N) time using a histogram sort:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct _list list_t;
struct _list {
    uint8_t value;
    list_t  *next;
};


list_t* sort_list ( list_t* list )
{
    list_t* heads[257] = {0};
    list_t* tails[257] = {0};

    // O(N) loop
    for ( list_t* it = list; it != 0; it = it -> next ) {
        list_t* next = it -> next;

        if ( heads[ it -> value ] == 0 ) {
            heads[ it -> value ] = it;
        } else {
            tails[ it -> value ] -> next = it;
        }

        tails[ it -> value ] = it;
    }

    list_t* result = 0;

    // constant time loop
    for ( size_t i = 255; i-- > 0; ) {
        if ( tails[i] ) {
            tails[i] -> next = result;
            result = heads[i];
        }
    }

    return result;
}

list_t* make_list ( char* string )
{
    list_t head;

    for ( list_t* it = &head; *string; it = it -> next, ++string ) {
        it -> next = malloc ( sizeof ( list_t ) );
        it -> next -> value = ( uint8_t ) * string;
        it -> next -> next = 0;
    }

    return head.next;
}

void free_list ( list_t* list )
{
    for ( list_t* it = list; it != 0; ) {
        list_t* next = it -> next;
        free ( it );
        it = next;
    }
}

void print_list ( list_t* list )
{
    printf ( "[ " );

    if ( list ) {
        printf ( "%c", list -> value );

        for ( list_t* it = list -> next; it != 0; it = it -> next )
            printf ( ", %c", it -> value );
    }

    printf ( " ]\n" );
}


int main ( int nargs, char** args )
{
    list_t* list = make_list ( nargs > 1 ? args[1] : "wibble" );


    print_list ( list );

    list_t* sorted = sort_list ( list );


    print_list ( sorted );

    free_list ( list );
}
```

Comment: It's been *proven* that no comparison-based sort algorthms exist that are faster than n log n.

Comment: No, it's been proven that no comparison-based sort algorithms *on general data* are faster than n log n

Comment: No, any sort algorithm faster than `O(n lg n)` would not be comparison-based (eg, radix sort). By definition, comparison sort applies to any domain that has a total order (ie, can be compared).

Comment: @bdonlan the point of "general data" is that there are algorithms which are faster for constrained input, rather than random input. At the limiting case, you can write a trivial O(1) algorithm which sorts a list given the input data is constrained to be already sorted

Comment: And that would not be a comparison-based sort. The modifier "on general data" is redundant, since comparison sorts already handle general data (and the big-O notation is for the number of comparisons made).

Answer (score 1):

As I know, the best sorting algorithm is O(n*log n), whatever the container - it's been proved that sorting in the broad sense of the word (mergesort/quicksort etc style) can't go lower. Using a linked list will not give you a better run time.

The only one algorithm which runs in O(n) is a "hack" algorithm which relies on counting values rather than actually sorting.

Comment: It's not a hack algorithm, and it doesn't run in O(n).  It runs in O(cn), where c is the largest value you're sorting (well, really it's the difference between the highest and lowest values) and only works on integral values.  There's a difference between O(n) and O(cn), as unless you can give a definitive upper bound for the values you're sorting (and thus bound it by a constant), you have two factors complicating the complexity.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it runs in `O(n lg c)`. If all of your elements are unique, then `c >= n`, and therefore it takes longer than `O(n lg n)`.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's an implementation](https://gist.github.com/sjswitzer/1dc76dc0b4dcf67a7fef) that traverses the list just once, collecting runs, then schedules the merges in the same way that mergesort does.

Complexity is O(n log m) where n is the number of items and m is the number of runs. Best case is O(n) (if the data is already sorted) and worst case is O(n log n) as expected.

It requires O(log m) temporary memory; the sort is done in-place on the lists.

(updated below. commenter one makes a good point that I should describe it here)

The gist of the algorithm is:

```
    while list not empty
        accumulate a run from the start of the list
        merge the run with a stack of merges that simulate mergesort's recursion
    merge all remaining items on the stack
```

Accumulating runs doesn't require much explanation, but it's good to take the opportunity to accumulate both ascending runs and descending runs (reversed). Here it prepends items smaller than the head of the run and appends items greater than or equal to the end of the run. (Note that prepending should use strict less-than to preserve sort stability.)

It's easiest to just paste the merging code here:

```
    int i = 0;
    for ( ; i < stack.size(); ++i) {
        if (!stack[i])
            break;
        run = merge(run, stack[i], comp);
        stack[i] = nullptr;
    }
    if (i < stack.size()) {
        stack[i] = run;
    } else {
        stack.push_back(run);
    }
```

Consider sorting the list (d a g i b e c f j h) (ignoring runs). The stack states proceed as follows:

```
    [ ]
    [ (d) ]
    [ () (a d) ]
    [ (g), (a d) ]
    [ () () (a d g i) ]
    [ (b) () (a d g i) ]
    [ () (b e) (a d g i) ]
    [ (c) (b e) (a d g i ) ]
    [ () () () (a b c d e f g i) ]
    [ (j) () () (a b c d e f g i) ]
    [ () (h j) () (a b c d e f g i) ]
```

Then, finally, merge all these lists.

Note that the number of items (runs) at stack[i] is either zero or 2^i and the stack size is bounded by 1+log2(nruns). Each element is merged once per stack level, hence O(n log m) comparisons. There's a passing similarity to Timsort here, though Timsort maintains its stack using something like a Fibonacci sequence where this uses powers of two.

Accumulating runs takes advantage of any already sorted data so that best case complexity is O(n) for an already sorted list (one run). Since we're accumulating both ascending and descending runs, runs will always be at least length 2. (This reduces the maximum stack depth by at least one, paying for the cost of finding the runs in the first place.) Worst case complexity is O(n log n), as expected, for data that is highly randomized.

(Um... Second update.)

Or just see wikipedia on [bottom-up mergesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists).

Comment: Having run creation perform well with "reversed input" is a nice touch. `O(log m)` additional memory should not be needed - just add runs to two list alternately until one is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy it into an array and then sort it.

- Copying into array O(n),
- sorting O(nlgn) (if you use a fast algorithm like merge sort ),
- copying back to linked list O(n) if necessary,

so it is gonna be O(nlgn).

note that if you do not know the number of elements in the linked list you won't know the size of array. If you are coding in java you can use an Arraylist for example.

Comment: What does this add over [Jørgen Fogh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1525419)?

Answer (score 0):

The question is [LeetCode #148](https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-list/), and there are plenty of solutions offered in all major languages. Mine is as follows, but I'm wondering about the time complexity. In order to find the middle element, we traverse the complete list each time. First time `n` elements are iterated over, second time `2 * n/2` elements are iterated over, so on and so forth. It seems to be `O(n^2)` time.

```
def sort(linked_list: LinkedList[int]) -> LinkedList[int]:
    # Return n // 2 element
    def middle(head: LinkedList[int]) -> LinkedList[int]:
        if not head or not head.next:
            return head
        slow = head
        fast = head.next

        while fast and fast.next:
            slow = slow.next
            fast = fast.next.next

        return slow

    def merge(head1: LinkedList[int], head2: LinkedList[int]) -> LinkedList[int]:
        p1 = head1
        p2 = head2
        prev = head = None

        while p1 and p2:
            smaller = p1 if p1.val < p2.val else p2
            if not head:
                head = smaller
            if prev:
                prev.next = smaller
            prev = smaller

            if smaller == p1:
                p1 = p1.next
            else:
                p2 = p2.next

        if prev:
            prev.next = p1 or p2
        else:
            head = p1 or p2

        return head

    def merge_sort(head: LinkedList[int]) -> LinkedList[int]:
        if head and head.next:
            mid = middle(head)
            mid_next = mid.next
            # Makes it easier to stop
            mid.next = None

            return merge(merge_sort(head), merge_sort(mid_next))
        else:
            return head

    return merge_sort(linked_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

Mergesort is the best you can do here.

Comment: See Simon Tatham's http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/algorithms/listsort.html

Comment: It would be a better answer if you would clarify _why_.