# Which is faster, sorting an array of structs or sorting a list of structures C?

Tags: c, arrays, list, sorting

I am faced with a challenge. I have data on a linked list of structs. Do l move the data onto an array of structs then sort it using qsort() or do l use merge sort?
This is the struct:

```
struct properties{
    char *path;
    char *name;
    char *extension;
    long int size;
    long unsigned created;
    long unsigned modified;
    long unsigned access;
    int permissions;
};
```

Comment: How you represent "list" in your code? Is it "array" vs. "list" or "qsort" vs. "merge sort" ?

Comment: Will you please clear it with an example??

Comment: Do you know how to sort a structure?? How can you move char, long int data on a single array?? It's not possible.

Comment: The best way to do this is perhaps to implement the linked list as an array, instead of a fully dynamic list. Then sorting becomes trivial. Alternatively, you could consider integrating the linked list with a pointer-based lookup table, so that each item in the linked list can get an index.

Comment: qsort() available in C can sort an array. It only needs you to specify the sort criterion to be used. You write a comparator function and provide its pointer to qsort().

Comment: if your properties are malloced separately inside your list (f.e. `struct list {struct properties *prop; struct list *next;};`) or your array you do not have to move so much data , just the pointers.

Comment: The problem l am faced with is deciding whether to sort data on a linked list or copy the data onto an array then sort it. I find it challenging to decide which would be faster. Of course moving the data to an array incurs a cost. But is that cost worth it? I think sorting an array using qsort() is faster than any method of sorting a linked list for the same data.

Answer (score 3):

I would create an array of pointers to the structs and sort the pointer array using `qsort`. Using pointers instad of copying the entire structs will use less memory.

Create a comparator like this:

```
int propertyComparator(const void *s1, const void* s2) {
    struct property *p1 = (struct property *)s1, *p2 = (struct property *)s2;

    /* compare p1 and p2, below is just an example */
    int result = strcmp(p1->name, p2->name);
    return result;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
 struct property *array;
 /* add code to allocate and create array */
 qsort(array, num_elements, sizeof array, propertyComparator);
```

**Edit:**

If you want to have a sorted linked list, mergesort is about as fast. Seems it depends on how fragmented the linked list is. 
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1525419/646887

The reason I prefer `qsort` is that it is part of the C lib, so I don't have to write and maintain so much code. And it is always a fast choice.

Comment: Thanks you all for your answers. Klas Lindbäck your answer is very informative. Does it mean that l traverse all the elements of the list and get     the pointer to each element storing them in the array?

Comment: Yes. And if you don't know the size you need to traverse it twice. First to calculate the size and then to collect the pointers.